# imagick WriteImage function is not working using Php 7.4

Tags: scripts, php, php7

I am trying to write images using imagick php extension but code break on write image line. I also comment this line in policy.xml

```
<!-- <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" /> -->
```

I am trying this code

```
private $path;
private $file;

function __construct($file){
    $this->path = "upload/".$file;
    $this->file = $file;
}
function convertDocument(){

    if ( !is_dir("custom/modules/Contacts/temp") ) {
        mkdir("custom/modules/Contacts/temp",0777,TRUE);       
        chmod("custom/modules/Contacts/temp", 0777);
    }

    $imagick = new imagick();
    $imagick->setResolution(200, 200);
    $imagick->readImage($this->path);
    $imagick->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
    $imagick->setImageAlphaChannel(11);
    $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('Read Image');

    $imagick->setImageResolution(2000, 2000);

    $imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');
    $pages = (int)$imagick->getNumberImages();
    $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('Get Image Pages: '.$pages);

    foreach($imagick as $i=>$imagick) {    
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('Write Images '.$i);
        $imagick->writeImage("custom/modules/Contacts/temp/".$this->file."_".$i.".jpg");
    }

    $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('After Writing images, START MERGING');

    $mpdf = new mPDF('en','Letter');

    for($p = 0; $p < $pages; $p++){
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('Write Image in PDF '.$p);

        $mpdf->WriteHTML("<img src='custom/modules/Contacts/temp/".$this->file."_".$p.".jpg' />");
    }

    $mpdf->Output('custom/modules/Contacts/temp/'.$this->file.'.pdf');
    $imagick->clear();

    $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('Conversion End .... ');



    return;
}
```

Please help me how i can solve this issue.

Comment: Where do you use the `Imagick` class?

Comment: please check now

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: i using this with job_queue. when code compile this line it give error cron job failed

Comment: Is there anyting in `/var/log/syslog` or in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, in case you run your own webserver? Please provide details.

Comment: in error.log getting this          [Mon Dec 19 19:46:21.567709 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 22563] [client ::1:33190] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'name' in /var/www/html/ftc_live/data/Relationships/One2MRelationship.php on line 107, referer: http://localhost/ftc_live/index.php?module=Contacts&offset=266&stamp=1671453039089100100&return_module=Contacts&action=DetailView&record=e2166290-3594-1390-bc32-6399841f4052

Comment: That is a warning, and moreover, there is no 'name' in your program. So this must refer to a different program.

Comment: yes its just warnning